# Why does my secure Travis CI environment variable not work?

Tags: github, travis-ci, badge, infection

Every time I deploy to Github, Travis CI says at the end of its report:

> `Dashboard report has not been sent: neither INFECTION_BADGE_API_KEY nor STRYKER_DASHBOARD_API_KEY were found in the environment`

I've tried setting the environment variable at least four times:

At first my `.travis.yml` file looked like this:

```
language: php

php:
  - '7.3'

install: composer update

script:
  - vendor/bin/infection --min-covered-msi=90 --min-msi=90

dd:
  secure: "A/s0...bS8="
```

This was because I had missed one of the dashes in the `--add` in [`travis encrypt STRYKER_DASHBOARD_API_KEY=<my-secret-uuid-key> --add`](https://infection.github.io/guide/mutation-badge.html) (from step 4 in the link).

When I fixed that it gave the same error message:

```
-dd:
-  secure: A/s0...bS8=
+env:
+  global:
+    secure: A/s0...bS8=
```

Each subsequent attempt gave the same error. Trying to generate a new key:

```
-    secure: A/s0...bS8=
+    - secure: iQra...Ol0=
```

Quoting the encrypted value:

```
-    - secure: iQra...Ol0=
+    - secure: 'iQra...Ol0='
```

Not using the `--add` option but manually copying from the console and pasting into the config file:

```
-    - secure: 'iQra...Ol0='
+    secure: "CPPE...3nk="
```

What's the right way to get this working?

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:** new free Travis CI accounts are now created on the professional server.

---

Hard to diagnose, easy to fix! [The instructions for creating a secure environment variable on Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#defining-encrypted-variables-in-travisyml) fail to mention that all new accounts are now created on the professional server ([travis-ci.**com**](https://travis-ci.com)), and no longer on the old free server ([travis-ci.**org**](https://travis-ci.org)), **even the free accounts!** What's even more confusing is that you can see the same account at both addresses!

So, to encrypt an environment variable, you must pass the server flag (`--pro` or `--com`) to `travis encrypt`:

```
travis encrypt --pro MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret --add
```

or

```
travis encrypt --com MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret --add
```

where you replace `MY_SECRET_ENV` with the name of your variable and `super_secret` with the actual value.

If you have an **old** free account that is still on [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org) you can continue to use:

```
travis encrypt MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret --add
```

or

```
travis encrypt --org MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret --add
```

For `travis encrypt` to output values that can be successfully decrypted, you **must** know which server your account is on, which is currently very confusing for new users.

Comment: wow, thanks. It seems as of now this is still not properly reflected in the docs: "
If you are using https://travis-ci.org, run:... " https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#encrypting-environment-variables